# How can I optimize Robot Framework to speed up testing of an Angular application?

Tags: angularjs, performance, robotframework

I know the basics of optimizing Robot Framework for speed on normal applications, but this is not a normal application. It's not a question of going as fast as possible, because if the code executes too fast on an Angular application, it'll try to click an element that isn't enabled or visible, or an element that doesn't exist yet. Timing issues abound, and the result is that I'm using a keyword (below) to slow down my program universally. The problem is that it's hard-coded, and I'm looking for a more "programatic" (programatical? I don't know the exact term) solution that will wait for an element to be clickable and then click it as soon as it is.

This is the keyword I use after every single click (`${SLOW_TIME}` is a global variable set to `0.5s`):

```
Slow Down
    #   EXAMPLE USAGE
    #   Slow Down   ${SLOW_TIME}
    [Arguments]     ${SLOW_TIME}
    Sleep           ${SLOW_TIME}
```

This is my current solution, which was written to verify that an element is ready to be clicked for test verification purposes, not speed. It's not complete (needs "Is Clickable") and occasionally causes the program to wait longer than it has to:

```
Verify Element Is Ready
    #   EXAMPLE USAGE
    #   Verify Element Is Ready     id=myElementId
    #   Click Element               id=myElementId
    [Arguments]                     ${element}
    Variable should exist           ${element}
    Wait until element is visible   ${element}
    Wait until element is enabled   ${element}
```

I'm aware that Robot Framework isn't built for speed, but for long tests I'm tired of doing nothing for 10 minutes waiting for it to finish, only to see that I have an incorrect `[Fail]`. If the solution involves Python, Javascript, or Java, I can work that in.

EDIT: I'm currently using ExtendedSelenium2Library, but its implicit waits don't always work, so I wanted a second layer of waiting, but only as long as necessary.

Comment: This isnt really an answer - but you said you are waiting for 10 minutes to see if it fails or passes. Why not create a little "sandbox" which has this new test you created, and see if that works. It it fails youll know within a few seconds and if it passes you can add it to the end of the main file. If that makes sense? Then when its added to the main file, it should work correctly, if the setup and teardowns are done correctly.

Comment: It does make sense and I usually do that, but sometimes the integration with the main file itself causes failures even though it shouldn't, and running the entire test to see if it works together takes that much time.

Comment: why are you calling `element should be visible` immediately after waiting for it to be visible? That seem redundant.

Comment: That was changed, but I originally had it there just to be certain.

Comment: i have exactly same issue

Answer (score 3):

First solution to explore would be to use libraries specifically designed for Angular based web applications, such as [AngularJsLibrary](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs) or [ExtendedSelenium2Library](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library). As far as I know, ExtendedSelenium2Library is the one that works best *(but perhaps not without any issues, I think it does have a few issues)*

Next thing to know is, given that your element indeed is visible, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's ready to be clicked. There are quite a few ways to get around this kind of issues.

One way is to put a sleep in your test setup, to give the page some time to fully initialize. I'm personally not a fan of this solution. This solution also doesn't work well for pages that load new content dynamically after the initial document was initialized.

Another way is to wrap your click element in a wait, either by writing your own in Python or, using something like [Wait Until Keyword Succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds)

Comment: I +1'd this answer because it includes useful info, but it does not answer my question and it refers to things that I'm trying to phase out as solutions. I'm currently using an advanced form of Sleep, but I want to phase that out for something more adaptable to individual elements. Also, I'm already using ExtendedSelenium2Library (my bad, I forgot to mention that I was doing that). However, I didn't know about Wait Until Keyword Succeeds, so thank you for that.

Comment: @BrandonOlson have you tried the AngularJSLibrary? If so, what is it that doesn't work for you? Having had a look at it's code it seems to me to contain the AngularJS specific sleep function you'd want.

Comment: I have not. Is it compatable with ExtendedSelenium2?

Comment: It is used on top of the Selenium2Library. So the keywords are complementary.